# How do I reset minibuffer when it seems to act like a regular buffer?

Tags: debugging, minibuffer

Occasionally the minibuffer acts somewhat like a "regular" buffer. By that I mean that when I type `C-x o` my cursor jumps to that buffer and then waits for me to type something.

But I can't write anything to it. For example, when I type `n` a new frame is opened.

The label for this buffer seems to be `*Minibuf-0*` - it is a minibuffer.

(Messages are still printed OK to the echo area, which is in the same location as the minibuffer.)

What I would like to do is "reset" the minibuffer so that it acts normally. I tried killing that buffer with `C-x k` but that doesn't change anything. The only thing that seems to fix it is a reboot of Emacs.

Is there a way to "reset" the minibuffer?

Comment: The `n` binding comes from `minibuffer-inactive-mode-map`.  AFAIK this is normally only used for those special frames which only contain a minibuffer.  I think what you're seeing is a bug and I'd recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  If you can find a way to reproduce the problem that would be particularly helpful to track downb and fix the bug.

Comment: Edited the question. It's about the minibuffer, not the echo area. One indication that there might be a bug is that the problem goes away (temporarily) if you reboot. Does it also go away if you just quit Emacs and restart Emacs (without rebooting)? Anyway, as @Stefan said, please do report this behavior, preferably with a recipe that starts from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Have you tried `M-x top-level`?

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions. 

@Drew - I feel that your edit will make the question harder to find for people whose echo area "turns into" a minibuffer. Am I misunderstanding the terminology? 

When I say "reboot" I mean it jokingly. I can actually reboot my computer faster than I can start Emacs on my Windows system. I just meant restarting Emacs.

When it happens again I will make a bug report. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@NickD had the answer! When my echo area "turns into" a minibuffer, I simply choose that buffer and execute the `top-level` function and the problem is solved. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: That may have enabled you to get out of the situation you were in. But your description of that situation suggests that there's a problem - perhaps a bug. and you said that this happens occasionally - it wasn't just a one-off.